# Проверка совпадения двух строк

Tags: bash

Каким образом написать условие, если в файле содержится "test", то выводить "OK"? Пытался по-разному и не получилось.

```
#!/bin/sh
file="`cat file.txt`"
if ($file == "test"); then 
 echo "OK"
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Работающий код:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
file="`cat file.txt`"
if [[ "$file" == "test" ]]; then
 echo "OK"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Одинарные круглые скобки служат для выполнения команд в подоболочке. Для выполнения сравнений следует использовать квадратные скобки, ака `test`, `[`, `[[`. Конструкция `if` `then` тоже не к чему, для выполнения второй команды в случае успеха первой можно использовать операторы связывание в последовательность.

```
[ "test" = "$(cat file.txt)" ] && echo "OK"
```

Comment: `cat` это часть пакета `coreutils` если речь о GNU/Linux

Answer (score 1):

grep/awk

```
if grep "test" file
then
    echo got you
fi
```

Только на bash:

```
file="./file"
while read -r line
do
    if [ "$line" =~ ".*test.*" ]
        echo got you
    fi
done <<< $file
```

Answer (score 1):

Ответ уже нашли, но я тоже пару примеров приведу)

```bsh
#Объявляем переменную
checker=`grep -ow "test" file.txt`
#башизм наверное, но если переменная не пустая, то выводить ОК
echo -en ${checker:+OK\\\n}
```

```bsh
#Одной строкой
#В файле test находится на отдельной строке
sed -n 's/^test$/OK/p' file.txt
#Или если это слово находится в строке с другим текстом
sed -nr 's/.*( |^)test( |$).*/OK/p' file.txt
```